# XCode 5 - Constraints not always kept at runtime when using a Tab View Controller

Tags: constraints, xcode5

In Xcode 5, I've opened a new project and added the following:

- A Tab View Controller with two Tabs (thus two View Controllers).
- In each Controller View, I've added a CollectionView, with both a Label and a Button under it.
- I've applied the Default constraints. No warnings.
- ... clicked Run.

In the iOS simulator, the first Tab looks ok, all elements in the View are aligned to the bottom of the layout, which is the top of the tab bar. Perfect.

When clicking on the second Tab, instead of aligning to the bottom of the layout, it aligns everything to the bottom of the container. So all the elements in the View drop in height by that much. Clicking back to the first tab will now show this incorrect positioning as well.

Strangely, rotating the device fixes this... showing the correct alignments in both tabs and for both orientations.

Any idea what am I doing wrong?
Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I now believe this is a bug in XCode 5.

I got around it by replacing the constraint for a pin, like so:

Editor -> Pin -> Bottom Space to Superview.